# How to change the mouse cursor to something else in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, cursor, sdl, mouse

How can I change the mouse cursor to something else in c++, Windows? I mean, change the pointer to another system default, for example, the hand icon.
I don't know what code I can provide you, since I don't really have anything for the mouse. The only thing I have for the mouse, that isn't in use, is to hide it. If this helps tell you what I use or anything like that, here:

```cpp
SDL_ShowCursor (SDL_DISABLE);
```

My c++ version isn't the newest, so that is something to note.
And hiding the mouse pointer and having a picture follow it isn't something I can do since it uses way too many resources and is slow.

Comment: did you try the SetCursor function?

Comment: or the WM_SETCURSOR window message?

Comment: I stumbled into a documentation from Microsoft, but it wasn't the clearest thing, so I searched for different ways.

Comment: Could you give me an example with one of them, please? To understand how they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SDL_SetCursor` If you want a system cursor, you can pass the return value of `SDL_CreateSystemCursor` to that function. See the documentation:

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetCursor

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateSystemCursor

https://web.archive.org/web/20210211163214/https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateSystemCursor

The documentation is currently somewhat lacking. The last link refers to the archived documentation, which contains the list of possible values for `SDL_CreateSystemCursor`

Example:

```cpp
SDL_Cursor* cursor;
cursor = SDL_CreateSystemCursor(SDL_SYSTEM_CURSOR_HAND);
SDL_SetCursor(cursor);
```